# python glob apply wildcard to search only in certain directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

How can I apply wildcard to glob to only search for files in certain directories?

e.g. I have these folders AABC, AADE, and archive.  I only want to run glob to get all the json files in AABC and AADE but not in the archive folder.

I've tried different variations of:

```
json_files = glob.glob("**.json", recursive=True)
```

such as:

```
json_files = glob.glob("AA**/**.json", recursive=True)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by *archive* folder?

Comment: @vishes_shell  a folder that is named "archive"

Comment: I feel silly,  glob.glob("AA**/**.json", recursive=True) works just fine, I was in the wrong directory.  But @Vlad 's answer is even better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution - `glob.glob('aa*/*.json'))`

And here's a test:

```
vladimir@vladimir-hp /tmp $ mkdir aab
vladimir@vladimir-hp /tmp $ mkdir aac
vladimir@vladimir-hp /tmp $ mkdir a
vladimir@vladimir-hp /tmp $ touch aab/1.json
vladimir@vladimir-hp /tmp $ touch aac/2.json
vladimir@vladimir-hp /tmp $ touch a/3.json
vladimir@vladimir-hp /tmp $ python3 -c "import glob; print(glob.glob('aa*/*.json'))"
>>> ['aac/2.json', 'aab/1.json']
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad,  this worked.  This is like the linux style wildcards

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two directories to search
you can use glob on each directory separately and concatenate the result:

```
json_files = glob.glob("AABC/*.json", recursive=True) + glob.glob("AADE/*.json", recursive=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @taras, this will work for now but I'm sure in the future I'll have more folders

Comment: @kouichi, so you can use a for loop over directories list and aggregate the data.